# onreadystatechange is not called in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

Here are my codes.

my function to send ajax request and return a value:

```
function myAjaxCall(){
   var myValue=0
   var async= false //I have to use synchronized request(otherwise my return value is 0)
   xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,async);

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
       ...
       myValue = SOMEVALUE;
   };

   xmlhttp.send();         

   return myValue
}
```

My other function will use the myAjaxCall function returned value

```
function otherFunc(){
   var x= myAjaxCall();
}
```

Things are working perfectly in this way except on **Firefox** browser, I know the reason is because in Firefox, if I use **synchronized** request, the `onreadystatechange` will not be called.

In my case, however, I have to use **synchronized** ajax request, otherwise `myAjaxCall()` function returned value is always the initail value "`var myValue=0`".

How to get rid of this firefox problem??

Comment: Don't use synchronized Ajax requests just to be able to return something straight away - they stop everything else on the page and can freeze the browser. It's *way* better to change the architecture of your program instead

Comment: What kind of architecture I can have in my case then.....

Comment: Use `otherFunc` as your callback handler and access `xmlhttp.responseText` therein.

Comment: Firefox versions before Firefox 4 don't fire onreadystatechange for synchronous XMLHttpRequest, as you noticed.  But since this is a synchronous request, why do you need the onreadystatechange handler in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Use a function pointer instead of an inline function to avoid this issue:

```
function myAjaxCall(){
   var myValue=0;
   var async= true;

   xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,async);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=foo;         
  }

function foo(bar)
  {
  var myValue = SOMEVALUE;
  return myValue;
  }
```

Functions control scope in JavaScript, so:

- The anonymous function creates a new scope, while the referenced function is in the global scope
- Moving the function out of scope avoids the namespace conflict
- myValue inherits a value in the new scope, while it does not in the global scope

Also, send should be done before onReadyStateChange

Comment: I always used a function, but this wont work now. I do not know why, but just calling the function without a new block it works!

Comment: @Ercksen The call is different because it doesn't create a new scope.